# Trying to get download link via Selenium

Tags: selenium

Trying to get the download link from this website to download the CSV file straight to a pandas dataframe with read_csv, however, having trouble scraping the link (from the href code).

To get to the csv download button, an initial click on the "Download Data" button is needed to open up another window.

The python code I have put together so far is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
URL = 'https://statisticsnz.shinyapps.io/covid_19_dashboard/'
driver.get(URL)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download_data-show"]'))
        )
    element.click()
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download_data-downloadData"]'))
        )
    
    outer = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
    
finally:
    driver.quit()

link = outer.find('a',href=re.compile('download_data-downloadData')).get('href') #I don't think this code line will work, but essentially trying to find the link to download with

df = pd.read_csv(URL + link)
```

The outer object returns the following html code and is missing the link that I need (href field is empty) to use directly in the read_csv file:

```
In[]: print(outer)
Out[]: <a id="download_data-downloadData" class="btn btn-default shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output" href="" target="_blank" download="">
          <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
          Download
        </a>
```

When I inspect the 'Download' button from chrome, it gives me the following html code with the link in the href field:

```
<a id="download_data-downloadData" class="btn btn-default shiny-download-link shiny-bound-output" href="session/c199b49c2d09d042041ee7682c9c5922/download/download_data-downloadData?w=6e59d758" target="_blank" download="">
          <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
          Download
        </a>
```

Any ideas why the link isn't showing when I scrape through Selenium, or maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: I have a related problem where the download link is not exposed via the href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the link directly of your download element like this:

```
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download_data-show"]'))
        )
    element.click()
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="download_data-downloadData"]'))
        )
    
    link = element.get_attribute('href')
    
finally:
    driver.quit()


df = pd.read_csv(link)
```

Comment: Sorry I probably should have been more specific about this, were you downloading the file to your computer? I'm trying to skip that step by downloading straight to an object which can be read into a pandas dataframe, without downloading to a computer first.

Comment: ah i see, well yes, i was just downloading the file to my pc.

Comment: I've edited my post and added the part of the code in at the bottom which shows what I'm trying to do, though I haven't correctly figured out that part yet as I can't get the link in the first place.

Comment: alirght, updated my answer, hope i understood you right.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately as the href is empty (see the contents of the 'outer' object above) the href link can't be pulled. Not sure why this can't be scraped with this method.